# Ionic Pro iOS build error: Unknown method 'error!'

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to build my Ionic 3 app for iOS using Ionic Pro. It already works on Android.

This is the error I have:

```
[08:47:12]: Unknown method 'error!', supported [:error, :important, :success, :message, :deprecated, :command, :command_output, :verbose, :header, :interactive?, :input, :confirm, :select, :password, :crash!, :user_error!, :shell_error!, :build_failure!, :test_failure!, :abort_with_message!, :not_implemented]
+------+------------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary               |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                 | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform       | 0           |
| 2    | create_keychain        | 0           |
| 3    | download_certs         | 1           |
| 4    | import_certificate     | 0           |
|    | update_project_codesi  | 0           |
|      | gning                  |             |
| 6    | shell command          | 0           |
| 7    | delete_keychain        | 0           | 
+------+------------------------+-------------+
[08:47:12]: fastlane finished with errors
[!] Unknown method 'error!', supported [:error, :important, :success, :message, :deprecated, :command, :command_output, :verbose, :header, :interactive?, :input, :confirm, :select, :password, :crash!, :user_error!, :shell_error!, :build_failure!, :test_failure!, :abort_with_message!, :not_implemented]
\e[91mFailed to upload ipa to storage please retry your build.
\e[0m Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

If you need more logs let me know. The error seems to say something about code signing. I just renewed all my production certificates yesterday, and I have the proper credentials set in my security profile.

Comment: Do you have the plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic" installed? Because I am facing a similar problem caused by that plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, forgot I posted this but I got around the issue. I never got the app to build with Ionic Pro, but I was getting the exact same error with Xcode and updating Xcode fixed the issue. Maybe Ionic Pro's iOS build tools are just slow to update?